# How to Dockerize multiple scripts that share requirements.txt and need frequent update

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker so I want to find best practices for my specific problem.

PROBLEM:

1. I have 6 python web-scraping scripts that run on same libraries (same requiraments.txt).
2. My scripts would need frequent updating (few times per week).
3. Also, my scripts have excel files from which they read and write stuff to, and I need to be able to update that excel files from time to time.

SOLUTIONS?

- Do I really need 6 images and 6 containers even doe my containers will have same libraries? I find it time consuming to delete container and image every time I update my code.
- For accessing files my excel files, I read about VOLUMES and I intend to implement them. Is that good solution?

Comment: Since your scripts have the same requirements they can share the same environment. This approach allows you to bind not only the excel but also your frequently updating scripts via volumes to the same container. However, utilizing the same container has its drawbacks, as pointed out by @fjc below.

Comment: It sounds like a Python [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) meets your needs: it has an isolated set of packages, but it can run code directly on your host without needing rebuilds when the scripts update, and it can directly read and write host files without special support.  Docker might not be the best match for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I really need 6 images and 6 containers even doe my containers will have same libraries?

It depends on technical possibility and personal preference. If you find a good, maintainable way to run all scripts in one Docker container, there's no reason you cannot do it. You could easily use a cron-like solution such as [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/willfarrell/crontab).

There are advantages to keeping Docker images single-purpose, though. One of them is clear isolation. If one of your scripts fails to run, you'll have one failing container only and five others that still run successfully. Plus you have full transparency over what exactly fails where.

> I find it time consuming to delete container and image every time I update my code.

I would propose to use some CI pipeline to do things like this. The pipeline would automatically build the images on a push, publish them to a registry and recreate the containers/services on your server.

> For accessing files my excel files, I read about VOLUMES and I intend to implement them. Is that good solution?

Yes, that's what volumes were made for: Accessing and storing data that isn't part of your image.